# I get no errors but my JSON statements are not even recognised. Can you tell my why?

Tags: android, json

In my logcat I'm getting these messages :

```
07-27 19:04:08.135 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister I/System.out: first step of the test, at least my button is recognised
07-27 19:04:08.135 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: illegal method access (call Lcom/android/volley/Request;.finish (Ljava/lang/String;)V from Lcom/example/chris/loginregister/RegisterRequest;)
07-27 19:04:08.135 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.android.volley.Request.finish, referenced from method com.example.chris.loginregister.RegisterRequest.access$super
07-27 19:04:08.135 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 17083: Lcom/android/volley/Request;.finish (Ljava/lang/String;)V
07-27 19:04:08.135 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00c8
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.example.chris.loginregister.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:43)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.example.chris.loginregister.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:37)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-27 19:04:08.485 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5457)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 19:04:08.495 15174-15174/com.example.chris.loginregister I/System.out: no, failed utterly
```

Any idea why code doesn't work ? I followed a tutorial on how to write a simple piece of information to a mysql database online and I get no errors in my code.

Here's my code :

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("first step of the test, at least my button is recognised");
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("second step, recognises my JSON");

                            if (success) {
                                System.out.println("yes, succeeded, it works, it recognises my PHP file");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("no, failed, but at least it recognises my JSON");
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("no, failed utterly");
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, responseListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                    queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try `System.out.println("json response: " + response)` and see if the response really is in JSON form (logcat says it's not)

Comment: @quidproquo I get a load of html type code like ,'PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
07-27 19:30:18.847 6777-6777/com.example.myfolder.loginregister I/System.out: <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in <b>/home/a7700712/public_html/Register.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br /> etc...etc...Any ideas?

Comment: probably something to do with your sql stuff then, doesn't seem like it's an android thing, although I'm not sure what `RegisterRequest` is, so maybe you're sending out a bad request?

Comment: Your server PHP is wrong. The line 29, in Register.php. Its in the logcat. The result received is HTML, and thus cannot be parsed into JSON

Comment: @Bonatti Yes, the errors were PHP related rather than Android related, thanks. Will post my answer later, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was PHP and MySql related rather than Android related.

Thanks to quidproquo in his comment, I printed my json response to the logcat, with

```
System.out.println("json response: " + response)
```

The tutorial I was following involved saving 4 variables to a database. I wanted to keep it really simple and just save one variable. I modified the tutorial PHP file to suit my needs but I missed some things. Namely :

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
```

should have been :

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)");
```

and

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $username);
```

should have been :

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
```

Fixed these, and then problem solved.